# C# Modbus RTU read data lenth are different

Tags: c#

I hope I can explain. And sorry for some text are in different language and I think that doesn't matter for this problem. I am trying to read data from Modbus RTU mode sensor. I created a read program and CRC check also. Data is successfully reading but the length of response are different like:-
[image: Main page]

The length determine the REC's 5th and 6th value like above :- (1E) or (1A).

And my Code is like

```
 public bool RsTransmitRec(string msg)
        {
            bool result = false;
            string outmsg = msg;

            spExec = true;
            try
            {
                sp.DiscardInBuffer();
                sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
                sp.Write(globalFrame, 0, globalFrame.Length);
                result = true;
                MainLogTextDisp("TR<" + outmsg + ">", Color.Blue); //TR command
                result = ResRecieve();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = false;
                spExec = false;
            }
            spExec = true;
            return (result);
        }
```

The above code is for Transmit and below code is for Response

```
 public bool ResRecieve()
        {
            bool result = false;
            tOutRec.TimeOutSet(0x100000);  //Start timeout monitoring                   
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (sp.BytesToRead > 5)//If I change number here when I     try to read holding register it will be the small length
                    {
                        byte[] bufferReceiver = new byte[this.sp.BytesToRead];
                        sp.Read(bufferReceiver, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
                        MainLogTextDisp("REC<" + dterr_chk.Display(bufferReceiver) + ">", Color.Blue);
                        sp.DiscardInBuffer();
                        sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
                        _recDoubleBuffer = dterr_chk.Display(bufferReceiver);
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    tOutRec.TimerInc();
                    if (tOutRec.TimeOutCheck() == true)
                    {
                        MainLogTextDisp("受信ﾀｲﾑｱｳﾄ", Color.Red);
                        result = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //何かエラーが起きたら
                    MainLogTextDisp(ex.Message, Color.Red);
                    EventAction(REC_ERROR);
                }
            }
            return (result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
DiscardInBuffer();
DiscardOutBuffer();
```

in your in code. It helped for me.